# How can I get my components state to update with React?

Tags: reactjs, components, lifecycle

I have a landing page that renders out a menu div and a main div.  This page has two states

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
        file: 'Main',
        menuFile: '',
   }
}
```

I mount my component and set the menuFile state

```
componentWillMount() {
   let test = 'menuMain';
   this.setState({
       menuFile: test
    });
}
```

I render menu and main div by calling them from this page

```
return (
 <div>
   <div className="menu">
     <Menu handleFileChange={this.handleFileChange.bind(this)} menuFile={this.state.menuFile} handleMenuChange={this.handleMenuChange.bind(this)} />
   </div>
   <div className="fileDiv">
      <File name={this.state.file} />
   </div>
 </div>
```

All of this works fine when the program loads.  The issues is when I click on a new menu, handleMenuChange() is called, but nothing happens.

```
handleMenuChange() {
  this.setState( {menuFile} );
}

ex. 
 menuFile = menuMain when the program starts.
 The program loads menuMain find.  When I click on a new menu, menuFile becomes the new menu name let's say...
 menuFile = menuOptions
 If I console log menuFile it reads 'menuOptions', but the menuOptions menu isn't rendered to screen.  
 If I start the program with menuFile = menuOptions - -  then menuOptions is rendered out.  However, if I click on a menu button, the state is updated but the new menu isn't rendered out.
```

The state is updated to the menuFile I wish to change the menu to, but the menu stays as the default menu.  For whatever reason it is not calling  with the new state and re-rendering the new menu.

How can I watch for a state update in order to make sure the page is re-rendered?

I imagine it's with shouldComponentUpdate() -  but I'm confused on how to use this.

Comment: Put argument to you your function handleMenuChange(menuName), and from Menu component call this function with parameter like this this.props.handleMenuChange('newName'). Also if you want for initial state 'menuMain' why you put it inside componentWillMount ?? you can set inside constructor your initial value and change it with other lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, `menuFile` isn't a prop for your Menu container. You should try something this

```
handleMenuChange() {
   this.setState( {menuName: 'newName'} );
}
```

Menu depends on `menuName` as I see

Comment: <Menu /> Calls back to <Landing /> with this.props.handleMenuChange(menuString); where menuString is let menuString = 'newName' for example

Comment: btw, you have miswrote this.handleMenuChagne

Comment: If I make handleMenuChange()  use menuName: ' ' instead, it still receives the new state name but the menu isn't change.  I'm not sure why I can type any menu name in componentWillMount() and get it to render correctly, but while the program is running - clicking on a menu option doesn't render out the new menu options

Comment: I still don't get where you use this.state.menuFile during rendering the component

Comment: updated the call to <Menu />  -  it should have read menuFile={this.state.menuFile}

Comment: Basically passes <Menu /> a menu name and menu renders out the correct menu to screen.  The problem is when I update the state of <Landing />, the menu isn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

You should update function:

`handleMenuChange() {
  this.setState( {menuFile} );
}`

to

`handleMenuChange(menuFile) {
  this.setState( {menuFile} );
}`